# Paypal Error "Sorry — your last action could not be completed"

Tags: paypal-sandbox

Please help i can't see payments received and sent in my account. Error is..
Message 3005

Sorry — your last action could not be completed

If you were making a purchase or sending money, we recommend that you check both your PayPal account and your email for a transaction confirmation after 30 minutes.

If you came to this page from another website, please return to that site (don't use your browser's Back button) and restart your activity.

If you came from PayPal's website, click the PayPal logo in the upper-left corner to return to our home page and restart your activity. You might have to log in again.
We are sorry, we are experiencing temporary difficulties. Please try again later. If this error occurred while making a payment, avoid duplicate payments by checking your Account Overview before resending a payment.

For some browsers, this problem can be resolved by clearing or deleting cookies.

Message 3005

Comment: I am getting the same error when I try viewing the account history in my  sandbox **seller's account** (whose credentials I am using with the PayPal REST API). I have tried Chrome, FF, and IE, clearing cookies in all before trying, but get the same error. I can view history in the **buyer's account** without any problems.